# edit object by a second form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to edit values of a main Object by an `edit_settings` form.

Now I pass the object to edit `By Ref` to the second form and I edit it directly. When I apply changes and I close `edit_settings` form nothing happen and the object still the same without changes.

Here my code:

**main form**

```
 Private Sub BtnEditStream1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEditStream1.Click
    Dim settingsStream = New StreamForm(myEncoder.streams(0), Me)
    settingsStream.Show()
 End Sub
```

**edit_settings form**

```
Public Sub New(ByRef stream As Encoder.Stream, ByRef settingsForm As SettingsForm)
    InitializeComponent()
    myStream = stream
    mySettingsForm = settingsForm
End Sub

...
doing stuff
...

Private Sub BtnApply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnApply.Click
    myStream.codec = CbCodec.SelectedItem
    myStream.bitrate = CbBitrate.SelectedItem
    myStream.url = TbURL.Text
    myStream.password = TbPassword.Text
    myStream.port = TbPort.Text
    myStream.mount = TbMountpoint.Text
    myStream.name = TbName.Text
    myStream.title = TbTitle.Text
    myStream.genre = TbGenre.Text
    myStream.description = TbDescription.Text
    myStream.isPublic = CbPublic.Checked
    mySettingsForm.UpdateMenu()

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

How can I do it in the best way?

Comment: How you check that _object still the same without changes_?

Comment: adding a stop and checking by the debug mode in visual studio or basically in the main form i have a sub updateMenu() (called before the closing of the child form) that update the text of the textboxes in the main form with the content (that should be overwritten by the child form). and there nothing change.

Comment: Is `Encoder.Stream` a class or a structure?

Comment: Stream is a Structure of the class Encoder

Comment: My idea and goal is to edit directly the Encoder object and have it ready in all forms i have.. i'm searching the best way to pass it around and do it

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question, although it's probably still good background info.

Comment: After declaring that `Stream` type properly, i.e. as per my answer, you should define it properly too, which means properties rather than fields and proper naming conventions, e.g. instead of `Dim url As String` or `Public url As String` you should have `Public Property Url As String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than being a structure declared within the `Encoder` class, that `Stream` type should be a class declared independently. Do that and then get rid of both `ByRef` keywords here:

```vb
Public Sub New(ByRef stream As Encoder.Stream, ByRef settingsForm As SettingsForm)
```

i.e.

```vb
Public Sub New(stream As Stream, settingsForm As SettingsForm)
```

and everything will work the way it should.